# HttpListener throttling?

Tags: .net, throttling, httplistener, http.sys

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229710.aspx) HttpListener is based on http.sys and "HTTP.sys provides connection management, bandwidth throttling, and Web server logging."

I need to limit the maximum amount of connections to server. What is the best way of doing this with HttpListener?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using HttpListener, that means that you're responsible for providing request/respond handling. If you were to create a new instance of [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) in your application, add a Prefix and call Start, it's not until your code either calls GetContext or BeginGetContext that your application code will respond to an incoming request.

If you call BeginGetContext (async), it will handle only one request until BegingGetContext is called again. So it's naturally limited (to just one connection). If you called it twice, it would handle two, and so on. While the connection attempts could be "queued", they'd only be handled one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

HttpListener maintains an internal queue of pending connections, so simply "not accepting the connection" does not help here, you need to clear its queue. This can be managed with a pool of threads (.NET <= 4.0) or with async connections (4.5+).

An example of the "thread pool + queue" approach is that of [Grapevine](https://github.com/scottoffen/Grapevine). In my R&D branch, [Interpspecific](https://github.com/tekhedd/Interspecific), I have enhanced this to limit the number of pending requests. It clears the HttpListener queue, and rejects requests with 500 errors if the queue is "full". From [RESTServer.c](https://github.com/tekhedd/Interspecific/blob/master/Grapevine/Server/RESTServer.cs):

```
    private void HandleRequests()
    {
        // Immediately accept and handle any requests:
        while (this.IsListening)
        {
            try
            {
                var context = this._listener.GetContext();
                this.QueueRequest(context);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                EventLogger.Log(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void QueueRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        lock (this._queue)
        {
            if (_queue.Count > MaxPendingRequests)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 503;
                context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                context.Response.Close();
                EventLogger.Log(
                    String.Format( "Request queue max size reached: {0}. Connection refused with 503 error.", 
                                   MaxPendingRequests ) );
                return;
            }

            this._queue.Enqueue(context);
            this._ready.Set();
        }
    }
```

This limits the number of total connections to MaxPendingRequests + the number of threads pulling connections from the queue. Hanlder threads pull from the queue (left as an exercise to the reader, or see RESTServer.c for examples).

The accept loop and connection limit will be different if you are using an async approach (much more scalable but 4.5+ only), but the general idea is the same: accept the HttpListenerContexts immediately and return 500 if you are "too busy".